# Can Sealed Content Types Be Deleted or Modified Programatically

Tags: 2010, content-type

I am creating some content types programaticaly and have set the sealed flag to true which seems to prevent deletion by users and code.  First how can it be deleted?  Second, what is the proper way to create a content type that I don't want users to change unless it is done programaticaly?

Comment: I noticed that grammatically changing the sealed property back to false allows deletion. so apparently I have my answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Sealed

> Optional Boolean. TRUE to prevent changes to this content type. You cannot change the value of this attribute through the user interface, but you can change it in code if you have sufficient rights. You must have site collection administrator rights to unseal a content type.
>
> If you do not include this attribute, SharePoint Foundation treats the content type as if the attribute was set to FALSE.

You need to unseal the content type to delete or change it using the GUI, and you do that with Site Collection Adminstrator rights. In code you can change it if you have sufficient rights, as I understand it, at least contribute rights.

Reference: [ContentType Element (ContentType)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544268.aspx)